# How Can I Set Custom Headers on a POST Request with PHP CURL?

Tags: php, curl

I have a bizarre curl problem. Example code is below. When I run this, the server does not receive the `CUSTOM_HEADER` header in the `$_SERVER` array. If I remove the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option, the header appears.

It looks like setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` overwrites the header(s) added in `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` (but I can't find this documented anywhere). Is that correct?

Changing the order doesn't seem to matter. I wasn't able to fix it by setting other options either.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://whatever.url';
$text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('CUSTOM_HEADER: TEST HEADER VALUE'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('text' => $text)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

The script I'm posting to just returns the `$_SERVER` info:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_SERVER);
die();
```

In the `$response` array, I get lots of request headers, but no `CUSTOM_HEADER`.

Is there some other way to send `POST` data to a URL with custom headers on the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curl side is working fine, but to fetch the request headers you should use [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php).

If you post to this script:

```
<?php echo json_encode( [
    'headers' => getallheaders(),
    'post'    => $_POST
] );
```

and print the `$response` like this:

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r( json_decode( $response ), 1 ) . "</pre>";
```

it should show

```
stdClass Object
(
    [headers] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Host] => whatever.url
            [Accept] => */*
            [CUSTOM_HEADER] => TEST HEADER VALUE
            [Content-Length] => 49
            [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        )

    [post] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, I do see the header with `getallheaders()`, thanks. Any idea why the header appears in `$_SERVER` when I don't include the POST fields? Seems crazy that it would appear for GET but not POST ...

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't on my install (Debian stable, Apache HTTPD 2.4.10, PHP 5.6.17). Usually the only HTTP headers that might end up in `$_SERVER` are the standard ones (`HTTP_HOST`, `HTTP_ACCEPT`, `HTTP_REFERER`, `HTTP_USER_AGENT`, `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE` and `REDIRECT_URL`/`REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` when you have a `.htaccess` with some redirects.). I think it's best not to rely on custom headers being in `$_SERVER`.